# What is the impact of upgrading MSBuild to VS2010 for projects targeting .NET Framework 2.0 and 3.5?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I’m working on the build process for a VS 2010 solution and some projects within it target the .NET framework 4.0. As far as I know, to have this type of solution built by TFS 2008 we will have to change the version of the MSBuild.exe file used by the build agent – modifying the TFSBuildService.exe.config file, pointing MSBuildPath entry accordingly.

Do you know if this will have any impact to existing project builds that target the 2.0 and 3.5 framework? Are you aware of any known issues with this type of set up?

Comment: No issues have been reported yet.  This site will still be here if you discover a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We made such upgrade from VS2008 to VS2010 without the TFS migration (so it's still in 2008 version). Only problem we had was with build machine (cause we have only one) so we had to configure SideBySide builds. We had projects in VS2008 solution with MSBUILD scripts, some of them were migrated to VS2010. 
Here's the solution http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/SideBySideTfsBuild.aspx

After changing we didn't experience any problems, yet:)

Comment: Thank you! My teammates reported the compiler wasn’t able to resolve a reference to System.TimeZoneInfo because it exists in two different assemblies in each framework version. So, they configured the solution described by the article you provided and now we have two different TFS services running side by side, one for each version of the framework.